# Easiest way to grep value from output in this string

Tags: bash, awk

I'm executing a command in a bash shell which outputs the following sample result:

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => 1303L
}
```

What is the simplest way to gather the value of "result" (in my case 1303) using bash/awk or other ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use grep like below,

```
grep -oP '"result"\s*=>\s*\K\S+' file
```

To get only the number present in the value of value of `result`

```
grep -oP '"result"\s*=>\s*\K\d+' file
```

To save the output to a variable,

```
$ var=$(grep -oP '"result"\s*=>\s*\K\d+' file)
$ echo "$var"
1303
```

Comment: I beg you pardon, is it going to a file ? would it be possible to assign it to a variable ?

Comment: `grep -oP '"result"\s*=>\s*\K\S+' infile > outfile`

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
awk '/result/{print +$3}' file
1303
```

Or to a variable:

```
var=$(awk '/result/{print +$3}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk as below:

```
var=$(awk -F'=> ' '/result/ {print +$2}' myfile)
```

Will result in 1303